# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS - no luks password prompt on Lenovo X390 after upgrades

Tags: boot, 20.04, encryption, lenovo, luks

I think, after some upgrades with apt-get upgrade on my Lenovo X390 with Ubuntu 20 I do not get any password prompt to decrypt the disk anymore. I just see the Lenovo logo and I’m not able to press anything, also typing the password and press enter is not working. The boot process is stuck on the Lenovo logo where normally was the password prompt below the Logo.

If I boot Ubuntu from an USB-Stick, I was able to decrypt the partition successfully and I was able to backup the data.

I tried to chroot the partition and executed the steps on https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/recovering-from-unbootable-ubuntu-encrypted-lvm-root-partition/

“update-initramfs -c -k all” executed without any failures and some files get updated on the unencrypted boot partition. But after a reboot I’m still not able to see the password prompt to decrypt the drive.

Do you have any further ideas (except reinstall Ubuntu) to resolve this issue?

I also don‘t know exactly how I can open the grub menu to modifiy the boot parameter. I tried shift and esc after the first Lenovo logo where I can press enter to select for example another boot device or enter the bios.

Can I even open the grub menu without decrypting the disk? Does that help me at all?

Here is the list of packages I updated before this behavior happened: https://pastebin.com/PuK7GYcf

```
/media/root/a5a282c7-9739-4c8e-9c46-cdde340c7f98/etc/crypttab
nvme0n1p3_crypt UUID=9d00eee1-b7dc-4262-bb65-cfbaeea9ce87 none luks,discard

/media/root/a5a282c7-9739-4c8e-9c46-cdde340c7f98/etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook
#
# Configuration file for the cryptroot initramfs hook.
#

#
# KEYFILE_PATTERN: ...
#
# The value of this variable is interpreted as a shell pattern.
# Matching key files from the crypttab(5) are included in the initramfs
# image.  The associated devices can then be unlocked without manual
# intervention.  (For instance if /etc/crypttab lists two key files
# /etc/keys/{root,swap}.key, you can set KEYFILE_PATTERN="/etc/keys/*.key"
# to add them to the initrd.)
#
# If KEYFILE_PATTERN if null or unset (default) then no key file is
# copied to the initramfs image.
#
# Note that the glob(7) is not expanded for crypttab(5) entries with a
# 'keyscript=' option.  In that case, the field is not treated as a file
# name but given as argument to the keyscript.
#
# WARNING: If the initramfs image is to include private key material,
# you'll want to create it with a restrictive umask in order to keep
# non-privileged users at bay.  For instance, set UMASK=0077 in
# /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
#

#KEYFILE_PATTERN=

/media/root/a5a282c7-9739-4c8e-9c46-cdde340c7f98/etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: I‘m using the latest Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) release from ubuntu.com

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I suspect I am having the same issue (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385790/cannot-detect-external-hard-disk-drive).

Comment: After one week or so, someone released a patch for shim. I started from an usb device and mounted the disk with the following steps and executed and apt update/upgrade: 
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 nvme0n1p3_crypt;
vgchange -ay;
mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /mnt;
mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/boot;
mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi;
mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc;
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev;
mount -t sysfs sysfs /mnt/sys;
chroot /mnt