# Cannot detect external hard disk drive

Tags: 20.04, usb, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have a few hard disk drives I use to make backups (they are in ext4 format and encrypted with LUKS). I have been using them regularly recently (two days ago) but now after two updates I am apparently not able even to find them with `fdisk -l`. There is no response of any kind I can see when I connect these disks.

All I have been able to deduce is that its probably something with the OS. Disk are not recognized in any USB port, and they are correctly detected in other laptop I got with a different Linux distro.

Any pointers to a solution are appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0bda:5511 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 003 Device 026: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 025: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 003 Device 024: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 27c6:533c Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 25a4:9311 VIA Labs, Inc.          USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: `lsusb` please with the harddrive.

Comment: update with the output of `lsusb`. It does not change with the disco connected or not.

Comment: Have you an older/previous kernel if so boot him up for test please.

Comment: Apparently, the latest update just fixed it alone. Answering the above anyway, I had not a different kernel available to boot from.

Comment: And wrong again. This is annoying...

Comment: Just figured out the kernel thing. I have in fact several versions, latest is `5.11.0-46-generic`. Booted from the previous one on backup (`5.11.0-44-generic`) and after reboot it detected the disk correctly. But after another reboot (without updates), it won't again. This is really, really weird.